# How to print 'Configuration Failure' log on the console which occurs at @BeforeTest of TestNG test class?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am running some 20 test classes during the regression test. There are some classes where I am getting the 'Configuration Failure' error. I am running my tests from the command line using maven commands. The thing is while going through the logs, I am not able to identify at which classes the mentioned error is coming. After the execution, I just get the info as :

```
===============================================
TestSuite
Total tests run: 124, Passes: 97, Failures: 8, Skips: 19
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 35
===============================================
```

But I want to print this error log on the console so that it will be easy for me to debug.
Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the detailed stacktrace at test-output. This folder generated by TestNG automatically.
Just open index.html by a browser.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this will surely help.